# Cart Price Rules to allow discount on limited products

Tags: cart, price, rules

I'm really struggling with Cart Price conditions.

I want to be able to offer a discount code (say, 10%) to customers, but on limited products.

I have created an attribute for my products already, "disallow discount". So I created the rule to work with products that are "disallow discount = no".

However, I want it to work on the basket if a customer has both types of products in - I need it to remove 10% on the products that are "disallow discount no", and not work on the "disallow discount yes". I can either get it to work on the whole basket, or none of it, I can't get the mix of on some and not others.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Here we need 2 conditions.

1. Apply the rule only if a valid product is available in cart.
2. Apply rule only to the products with `Disallow discount = no`

**For First point:**
In cart price rules, on the conditions select `Products subselection` and set something like below. Instead of the sale attribute Select your `Disallow Discount` attribute.
[image: Cart Rule Condition]

**For Second point:**
In actions section, select the desired discount value (`10`) and set the conditions as below.
[image: Cart Rule Action]

This will ensure only the products matched with this rule gets the discount.